# Adding a Dotted red line under characters in a UITextView

Tags: ios6, uitextview, spell-checking

I am trying to create my custom spell checker for the UITextView.

To show that a word is misspelled, I need to add the "red dotted line" under the misspelled word.
To do that, here is what I thought would work -

I create a dictionary which contains the values for the key `NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName`.
However, what this does is, it does underline the characters but it does not have a dotted pattern. 
Also, setting the strokeColorAttribute also does not seem to have any effect.

Here is my code -

```
    NSMutableDictionary *misspelledAttributes = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [misspelledAttributes setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kCTUnderlineStyleThick|kCTUnderlinePatternDot] forKey:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName];
    [misspelledAttributes setObject:[UIColor redColor] forKey:NSStrokeColorAttributeName];
```

To set the attributes to a attributed string for a particular range -

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attrString = [self.textView.attributedText mutableCopy];
[attrString addAttributes:misspelledAttributes range:wordRange];
```

It would be great if someone could help me with this and point out what I am missing/doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are going to have to find an approach other than NSAttributedString.

As far as I can tell, your only value choices in iOS for [NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nsunderlinestyleattributename) are NSUnderlineStyleNone or NSUnderlineStyleSingle, which represent numbers.

[NSUnderlineColorAttributeName](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nsunderlinecolorattributename) support iOS 7.0+.

Comment: I guess it's possible this is new, but in my previous testing, and the doc I link to, it says: Availability: Available in OS X v10.0 and later.